# How to play changed lyrics

Tags: mixing, homerecording

Suppose I have a mp3 song and its lyrics, for example dream on by Aerosmith

```
Every time I look in the mirror
All these lines on my face getting clearer
```

And I want to change the lyrics, basically one-two words in the whole lyrics

```
Every time I look in the sky
All these lines on my mirror getting clearer
```

In above, I changed sky from mirror in first line and face to mirror in the second. Now I want to play this changed lyrics with same music, if possible also keep the voice of the singer same. Is there any application, software or online resource that can do this?

Comment: Get a Karaoke track and find a singer that can sing the entire new lines that you want to change and record.  Can't be done with software alone.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible.

The first problem is that you have a stereo track and not the separate tracks (the vocals separated from the band). There are some techniques to remove or isolate vocals but they rarely ever work 100%.

The second problem is that even you if you had separate tracks you can't just change lyrics unless you have Steven Tyler on hand to rerecord them for you. Though, [maybe some day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuZGK7QolaE).